# Better approach to handle multiple editable fields in a block - Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a block of div inside there are several elements which are editable. (snapshot 1 ) On click of 'edit' option the label showing the text should be hidden and corresponding input field be visible (snapshot 2)

This is my approach:
Add a method each on every editable button and write a corresponding method  which will hide the label and show the textbox and vice verse.

But then I'll have to repeat this behaviour for all the editable fields. Is there a better approach? For e.g in Jquery I could just add a common class to all of the edit buttons and and attach a method on click of it.

[image]

[image]

Sample Code (Of course, I can make this better but just see the approach):

```
<div>
  <label>External ID</label>
  <span *ngIf="glyphExternalId==='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'">{{externalId}}</span> 
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name=""  
  [(ngModel)]="externalId" *ngIf="glyphExternalId!=='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'">
  <i [ngClass]="glyphExternalId" (click)="updateExternalId()"></i>
  <input type="checkbox" name="iccEnabled" id="iccEnabled"><label for="iccEnabled">ICC Enabled</label>
</div>



glyphExternalId="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
  updateExternalId(){
    this.glyphExternalId = this.glyphExternalId == 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'? 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok': 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil';

  }
Similarly for each of the editable items
```

Comment: Kindly provide code and if possible plunker

Comment: @TheDictator provided a sample rough code in edit. Of course, I can make this better but just see the approach.